# python can't find import module mysteriously

Tags: python, module

I met some python import problems in the past few months. They took me lots of time to locate and now I want to make it clear.

I have a Django project like:

```
-dir
    -app1
        fun1.py
        util.py
    -util
        http.py
    -app2
        fun2.py
```

```
# fun1.py
from util.http import http_retry
```

```
# util.py
def other_funcs():
    pass
```

```
# http.py
def http_retry:
    pass
```

Situation 1: When I run `python app1/fun1.py` in `dir`, I want to import the `dir/util/http.py`. However, python imported `dir/app1/util.py`. I have to change the file name of `dir/app1/util.py` to make it work.

Situation 2: Sometimes I want to run the scripts instead of Django server. But I have to add

```
import sys
sys.path.add("/xxx/xxx/dir/")
```

to make it work.

What confuses me more is that both errors just sometime popped mysteriously. Sometimes on my Mac/remote server in Django/script it's ok, after some weeks it's wrong. I searched some blogs about python module. But they are not deep enough to solve my problem.

Comment: Just read this and your life is forever changed: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html

Comment: @BaileyKocin Yeah, it is changed.